# Differences between a norm in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Consider the definitions of matrix norm and subordinate matrix norm from

[Matrix Norm set #2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367752/matrix-norm-set-2/367998?noredirect=1#comment789786_367998)

and let $A$ a **real matrix** and $\|\cdot\|$ a vector norm over $\mathbb{C}^n$. Define
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|A\| & = & \sup_{v\in\mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}}\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|},\\
 |A|  & = & \sup_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}}\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}.
\end{eqnarray*}

1. Show that $\|A\| = |A|$ if the vector norm is any of the norms $\|\cdot\|_p$, $p=1,2,\infty$. Is the result also true for the norms $\|\cdot\|_p$, for the remaining values of $p \geq 1$?
2. Give an example of a matrix $A$ and a vector norm for which  $|A| \leq \|A\|$.
3. Prove that $\rho(A) < |A|$.

---

Please, somebody can help me with this question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find an answer to 2. & 3. (which I presume should read $\rho(A) \le |A|$) in http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/NormReal.pdf.

Comment: Also, I assume 2. should read $|A| < \|A\|$, otherwise the $p=1,2,\infty$ norms from 1. will suffice?